# Is there a way to dynamically generate a dictionary from looping thru a directory of files

Tags: python

I have some files like below in a directory where I'm looping thru directory to processed each one.

- `tenents.txt`
- `people.txt`
- `customers.txt`
- `clients'.txt`

I'm trying to dynamically create a dictionary like below i have search high and below and tried similar examples on here but can't get the desired output . Need someone's help in identifying what I'm doing wrong :

#### expected output:

```
[{'input' : 'tenents.txt' , 'config':'tenents.json'},{'input' : 'people.txt' , 'config':'people.json'}
 {'input' : 'customers.txt' , 'config':'customers.json'},{'input' : 'clients.txt' , 'config':'clients.json'}]
```

actual output from my code:

```
[{'config': 'tenents.json','input': 'tenents.txt'}]
[{'config': 'people.json','input': 'people.txt'}]
[{'config': 'customers.json','input': 'customers.txt'}]
[{'config': 'clients.json','input': 'clients.txt'}]
```

Also why are the keys in the wrong order from left to right. why is schema key coming before the input key even after i try to sort it.

Snippet of my code that's not working:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint

filelist = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
            keys = ['input', 'config']
            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            cname = filename.rstrip('.txt') + '.json'
            names = [[filename, cname]]

            filelist = [{k: v for k, v in zip(keys, n)} for n in names]
            pprint(filelist)
```

I'll appreciate someone's help. I'm using anaconda python 3.

Comment: dictionary doesn't maintain order

Comment: If the order matters use a list or `OrderedDict`. ... Does it matter?

Comment: What are the possible inputs? Do you really only need to change the file extension? You should probably use pathlib instead of os.path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems to work:

```
file_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            file_list.append({'input': file, 'config': file.replace('.txt', '.json')})
print(file_list)
```

I just created a file list like you did, and appended a dictionary to it for each file with the respective values.

Comment: Oh wow. you make this look so easy. Thank you so much for your help. It appears the pprint is what's changing the order of the keys.